# How to implement multi device Login in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, clearance

I'm using clearance(1.3.0) gem with rails(3.2.18) and ruby(2.0). Now i want to implement multi device login & maintain their devise token to push notification.
When i logout from one device, it should not affect the other login.

Comment: Just add a new table that contains token and device information, based on  that you can maintain multiple login

Comment: Thanks i am using same approach , but then i have to tweak sign_in, sign_out call & current_user logics as i have to maintain remember_token in new user_client model

Answer (score 0):

Clearance only supports a single remember token for each user. To continue using Clearance and add multiple user tokens that can be signed out individually, you will need to override quite a bit of Clearance.

There is currently an open discussion about adding this feature to Clearance 2.0: https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/issues/675